# Benefits of External Tables vs. UTL_FILE

Tags: oracle, plsql

I am writing an application in PL/SQL that takes a .csv flat-file, reads it, does some data processing on it, and then decides which of several tables to update, insert into, or delete.

I have the option of using the UTL_FILE.GET_LINE functionality to process a single record at a time, parsing it with various REGEX tools, storing the data temporarily in some variables, and then doing work with it (making decisions, updating tables, etc.)

I ALSO have the option, of creating an External table, and then just stepping through it using a cursor on said external table (using a for each loop for performance)  I should still be able to do all of the same things with the data(making decisions, updating tables, etc.)

I have looked around, and a couple of forums suggest that External Tables are the preferred solution to this, as they scale better, are faster, and more reliable.  I have not, however, heard a why.   Oracles documentation on utl_file and/or external tables does not talk about why one might be faster than the other, so I'm curious if anyone has some more information or references that I do not about what would make one perform better over the other.

Answer (score 1):

The performance difference is quite simple: UTL_FILE is a PL/SQL package, while external tables use the SQL*Loader code written in C.

If you have enough data, you can even load external tables in parallel with minimal effort f.i. ALTER TABLE my_external_table PARALLEL 4;

External tables can be used in bulk mode (INSERT INTO my_table SELECT ... FROM my_external_table JOIN my_lookup_table USING (lookup_column)).

External tables can be set to transactionally safe mode (REJECT LIMIT 0), so the above INSERT either works or rolls back.

Do you need more reasons?

Answer (score 0):

If the file has data that has a known structure/file format then external table is the way to go.  UTL_FILE is at a different abstraction level - you are now just working with a file - your use of UTL_FILE will be brittle and likely introduce bugs.  The deciding factor should not be performance; however I doubt you will be able to 'outperform' Oracle's external table implementation by rolling your own using REGEX and UTL_FILE.